# Get Rows that are include one many to many. but not another

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I am having a little trouble with this query. I want to filter my Features down for all features that have applicabilities that have include the name 'G6', but that also do not have a many to many relationship with applicabilies that have the name 'n2'. I have right now:

```sql
SELECT inner.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT feat.* 
    FROM Features feat
        INNER JOIN Feature _has_Applicability feat_app 
            ON feat_app.feature_id = feat.id
        INNER JOIN Applicability app 
            ON feat_app.applicability_id = app.id 
                AND app.name like '%G6%'
    WHERE feat.deleted_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY feat.id
    ) AS inner
    INNER JOIN Feature_has_Applicability out_feat_app 
        ON out_feat_app.feature_id = inner.id
    INNER JOIN Applicability app 
        ON out_feat_app.applicability_id = app.id 
            AND app.name NOT LIKE '%N2%'
GROUP BY inner.id
HAVING count (*) = 1
```

I have a many to many from Feature to Applicability where

Feature
`id` INT PRIMARY
`deleted_time` DATETIME

Applicability
`id` INT Primary
`name` VARCHAR(45)

Feature_has_Applicability
`feature_id` INT
`applicability_id` INT

Example:
I have feature A with applicabilities named N2 and G6
I have feature B with applicability G6, N7
I have feature C with applicability N2

I want only feature B to be returned as it includes G6 but not N2.

G6 is A and N2 is B in regards to features that have a many to many relationship with them.
[image: Ven diagram]

This still seems to return features that have an applicability to 'n2'. Can you see what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make it much easier for other people to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added an example with desired result on text form

Comment: I added a ven diagram to explain. This diagram is usually associated with a left join, I am just having a hard time coding out the set theory here with these many to many relations. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sub-query seems fine. Personally, I'm not sure why you still get *'n2'* records based on this query alone without seeing the database. Maybe because you use an upper case *'N2'* in the query? Operators are case sensitive.

Although I suggest you to use `NOT EXISTS`. It'd make the code much more understandable with its intention. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  features feat
  INNER JOIN feature_has_applicability feat_app ON feat_app.feature_id = feat.id
  INNER JOIN applicability app ON app.id = feat_app.applicability_id
    AND app.name LIKE '%G6%'
WHERE
  feat.delete_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
       *
    FROM
      feature_has_applicability out_feat_app
      INNER JOIN applicability out_app ON out_app.id = out_feat_app.applicability_id
        AND app.name LIKE '%N2%'
    WHERE
      out_feat_app.feature_id = feat.id
   )
```

Using `NOT EXISTS` help to streamline the code. So in this case, the main query is much easier to understand, where we want to find Feature records that have a *'G2'* applicability. But then we only want records that do NOT have *'N2'* applicability owned by the selected Feature records' ID.

I'm confused with the purpose of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING count(*) = 1`. If you group it by its ID and expect each group to only have one record, then doesn't that mean each filtered Feature record only has a single *'G6'* Applicability record and thus you don't need to worry about filtering out *'N2'* records? Unless there are weird cases like having both *'G6'* and *'N2'* keywords in the same Applicability record.

Another pointer, for your sub query, you should never use reserved keywords as an identifier. In this case, you called your sub-query as *"inner"*, which is a bad practice and may not run at all in other database engines. Perhaps you can call it as *"g2_feature"*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! Great suggestions and your query is much easier to follow. The only thing I had to do was a distinct(feat.id) in my select (or a group by feat.id would accomplish the same thing). I appreciate it!

Comment: So you want to just get Features record without any other information from Applicability record? Then that query can be further improved by moving the `INNER JOIN` clauses as another `EXISTS`  condition. That way you don't need to use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP` anymore, those clauses hint that query will group data together although you that's not the intention.